# useLocation location members are empty within HashRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, window.location

When using a `HashRouter`, and within a component using `useLocation`, there is a discrepancy between the `window.location` object and the `location` object from `useLocation`.

As I am writing this I have noticed there may be a confusion around what `useLocation` is actually pointing to. The `pathname` from `useLocation` seems to actually be the `window.location.hash` without the `#`. But the `hash` seems to not be pointing at anything at all.

Honestly I wasn't sure if I should've posted this as an issue on react-routers Github, but I wanted to post this here in case there is some fundamental piece of info I'm missing about how `useLocation` is supposed to work (more importantly in relation to what router you are using).

Does `useLocation` behave differently when you wrap it in `<BrowserRouter>` vs `<HashRouter>` vs `<MemoryRouter>` etc.?

Values from `window.location`:

```
{
  pathname: "/myPage/"
  hash: "#/testpath/123"
  search: ""
}
```

Values from `location = useLocation()`:

```
{
  pathname: "/testpath/123"
  hash: ""
  search: ""
  key: "abc123"
  state: null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using a `HashRouter`, and within a component using `useLocation`,
> there is a discrepancy between the `window.location` object and the
> `location` object from `useLocation`.
>
> As I am writing this I have noticed there may be a confusion around
> what `useLocation` is actually pointing to. The `pathname` from
> `useLocation` seems to actually be the `window.location.hash` without
> the #. But the hash seems to not be pointing at anything at all.

The `HashRouter` router uses the path defined after the ***first*** hash of the URL.

For example, given:

- Route: `<Route path="/testpath/123" element={....} />`
- URL: `"https://..../#/testpath/123"`

The `location` returned from the `useLocation` hook may look like:

```
{
    "pathname": "/testpath/123",
    "search": "",
    "hash": "",
    "state": null,
    "key": "ff78cgdt"
}
```

As compared to `window.location`

```
{
    "ancestorOrigins": {
        "0": "https://...."
    },
    "href": "https://..../#/testpath/123",
    "origin": "https://....",
    "protocol": "https:",
    "host": "....",
    "hostname": "....",
    "port": "",
    "pathname": "/",
    "search": "",
    "hash": "#/testpath/123"
}
```

Given:

- Same route: `<Route path="/testpath/123" element={....} />`
- URL: `"https://..../#/testpath/123#foo"`

Then the `location` object would look like:

```
{
    "pathname": "/testpath/123",
    "search": "",
    "hash": "#foo",
    "state": null,
    "key": "r7bfxju4"
}
```

```
{
    "ancestorOrigins": {
        "0": "https://...."
    },
    "href": "https://..../#/testpath/123#foo",
    "origin": "https://....",
    "protocol": "https:",
    "host": "....",
    "hostname": "....",
    "port": "",
    "pathname": "/",
    "search": "",
    "hash": "#/testpath/123#foo"
}
```

Notice the only difference now is that the `"foo"` is now part of the `location` object, the "hash" of the route path the app's router is using. It also is included in the hash of `window.location`, e.g. everything after the *first* hash.

> Does `useLocation` behave differently when you wrap it in
> `<BrowserRouter>` vs `<HashRouter>` vs `<MemoryRouter>` etc.?

No, not really. These routers all manage and/or maintain their own internal history object and state, e.g. what `location` is in each context. The `BrowserRouter` couples internal routing/navigation actions to a browser's DOM, and similarly the `HashRouter` uses ***just*** the hash of what is effectively a static location, e.g. an app hosted/served from a specific directory on a server. The `MemoryRouter` is intended to be used in non-DOM environments, e.g. Node environments like Jest testing, etc.

Depending on which router you use, and what the URL path/etc value is, some of the `location` properties may not be set, but the `useLocation` hook and `location` object is basically the same regardless.

I don't believe there is a bug or issue to file here as everything you described seems like reasonable behavior given the `HashRouter` and the console logging you used.